# how can we show associated simple product information of configurable product in product view page in magento

Tags: magento, product, configurable

how can we show  associated simple product information of configurable product in product view page in magento.like sku number of simple product should be shown when we select an option from the drop down  of configurable product in product view page.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest the Simple Configurable Products extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html. There are some tweaks you need to make for recent versions of Magento but it works perfectly for me in 1.8.1.

**Update with pointer to tweaks**

I've pasted in below a review comment by tzvimoshe from the magentocommerce.com entry for SCP.

> To get this to work in 1.7 you need to 1) apply fix from Github AND 2)
>   apply the fix to that as well. See 1)
>   https://github.com/magdev/magento-configurable-simple/blob/6d88e5e1846713f579f79905dc3ed35112772ebc/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php
>   2)
>   https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/pull/85
>   For everyone's convenience I have posted the complete fix on pastebin.
>   See http://pastebin.com/spVj88T4 just paste into app / code /
>   community / OrganicInternet / SimpleConfigurableProducts / Catalog /
>   Model / Resource / Eav / Mysql4 / Product / Indexer / Price /
>   Configurable.php

Comment: Do you recall what the required tweaks are?

Comment: I've pasted some information in to my answer. Google magento and simple configurable products too as there's some useful stuff out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty big thing you are asking here.
I don't have a complete solution, but I can give you a nudge in the right direction.
I recommend you [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher).
It does not do what you need, but instead it changes the product dropdowns to clickable labels. This feature can be disabled if your don't need it.
But here is what you might be able to use from it.
When changing a product configuration, it changes the configurable product image if you configure it to do so.

You can take it and modify it so when it changes the image it changes also the name and/or sku.
This is the line that changes the product image: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/js/easylife_switcher/product.js#L274.
You can inject your logic there to change the sku or name also.
This is the line that collects the simple product images:  https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/app/code/community/Easylife/Switcher/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Configurable/Config.php#L136.
You can add a similar one that would collect all your skus and/or names.
After that you will need to add some markup around the name or sku so you can easily identify it in the DOM with js.
I hope this helps you at least a little.